# rendering with/without shadows

Tags: rendering, animation, shadows, render-passes

I'd like to render 60 frames of animation, where actually nothing moves, just the sunlight and the shadows are moving a little bit. I'd like to differenciate the objects and the shadows and render them differently, but I'm not sure what's the best solution for this.

I'd like to draw something on the image without any sunlight/shadows, and overlay shadows afterwards.

I deleted the sun and windows/walls, and then rendered a still image. I'm also trying to render the shadows animation with the sun and windows/walls are with them again, with editing render pass(shadow) to individual file output.

I'm not sure I'm doing this right, because I think if I can differenciate the shadows with render passes, then I could also render the image without any shadows, also with render passes.

It there better/faster solution for this? The file itself is pretty huge, and it's taking forever to render 60 frames, even in Rebusfarm.